# Insert different HTML based on switch statement

Tags: jquery

I have this element in a form:

```
<a id="dyLink" href="">
```

Depending on calculation of the form the `href` tag changes depending on different cases:

```js
switch (week) {
  case 1:
    link = "https://schwangerschaftswochen.ch/die-erste-schwangerschaftswoche/";
    break;
  case 2:
    link = "https://schwangerschaftswochen.ch/die-zweite-schwangerschaftswoche/";
    break;
  case 3:
    link = "https://schwangerschaftswochen.ch/die-dritte-schwangerschaftswoche/";
    break;
  case 4:
    link = "https://schwangerschaftswochen.ch/die-vierte-schwangerschaftswoche/";
    break;
  case 5:
    link = "https://schwangerschaftswochen.ch/geburtsterminrechner/#lepopup-Newsletteranmeldung";
}

jQuery("#dyLink").attr("href", link)
```

However I don't want to have different links, but different HTML elements for every case. I have no idea about coding. How can I do it?

Comment: Put the HTML string in the cases of the `switch` and `append()` it to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery you may replace your element with another using `.replaceWith` to completely replace an element with another one.

Using your code as base you may do something like this:

```
switch (week) {
  case 1:
    link = '<a href="anything" id="some-id">A link</a>';
    break;
  case 2:
    link = '<div class"clannName">The Content</div>';
    break;
  case 3:
    link = '<input type="text" name="inputName">';
    break;
  case 4:
    link = '<pre>Preformatted test</pre>';
    break;
  case 5:
    link = '<button type="button">Click!</button>';
}

jQuery("#dyLink").replaceWith(link);
```

Comment: Thanks your code is working... Mine is still not, and I can't figure out why.

I placed in the code. "<div class='lepopup-inline' data-slug='Newsletteranmeldung'>boom</div>"

If you test it on my site https://schwangerschaftswochen.ch/geburtsterminrechner/ (until week 4) you can see that it's not working.

Comment: I see the `boom` div on your site, so the script is working. Keep in mind that it can work only once because when you replace the element with `id=dyLink` it does not exist anymore, so the second time you use `jQuery("#dyLink")` you find nothing. One solution could be to give the same id to all injected component.

Answer (score -1):

include the html you want to put in every case :

E.g:

HTML: where you want to put the HTML :

```
<div class="mydiv"></div>
```

JS:

```
    switch(week)
                {
                    case 1:
                    document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML="<a href='case1.com' id='case1' >"
                    break;
                    case 2:
                    document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML="<a href='case2.com' id='case2' >"
                    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks your code is working... Mine is still not, and I can't figure out why.

I placed in the code. "<div class='lepopup-inline' data-slug='Newsletteranmeldung'>boom</div>"

If you test it on my site https://schwangerschaftswochen.ch/geburtsterminrechner/ (until week 4) you can see that it's not working.